# Facebook Apprequest: Redirect user to a custom url when click on the app request notification

Tags: facebook, facebook-app-requests

I am using following direct url method to send app request to my facebook friends:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?
app_id=APP_ID&
message=MESSAGE&
redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

And it is working fine but i actually need to redirect the user who received this app request notification to my site's login page (http:///accounts/login/) when he click on this notification.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming you tried to change redirect_uri to that of course?

Comment: http://www.example.com/response should given as http://accounts/login

Comment: `redirect_uri` says where the user _using that dialog_ shall be redirected afterwards. Requests always go to your canvas app, so your only option is to redirect from there (using JavaScript). But please be aware that canvas apps with the sole purpose of redirecting users out of Facebook are against platform policies.

Comment: SalGad, Thirumalai murugan:But facebook docs defines the redirect_uri is for the one who sends the notification.And I need the receiver who get the app notifications  sent by me to be redirected. Thanks!!

Comment: CBroe: I think that would be fine. Thanks!!